# Executable created with py2exe freezes when using webkit's open(url) function

Tags: python, webkit, py2exe, cairo, gui2exe

I am using the [GUI2Exe program](https://code.google.com/p/gui2exe/) to create my executable, and while I can build and start the executable, it crashed on a call to "open" the url. This is repeatable not only in my program but in the super simple [14 line webkit browser](http://ardoris.wordpress.com/2009/04/26/a-browser-in-14-lines-using-python-and-webkit/). And when
using cx_freeze instead of py2exe.

The "problem signature" reported in the windows diagnose thing points it's finger at the libcairo-2.dll

Commenting out the browser.open(url) call results in the window opening (albeit without the contents that the browser would be loading) and responds to the close command.

```
gobject.threads_init()
window = gtk.Window()
browser = webkit.WebView()
#browser.open("http://www.google.com")
window.add(browser)
window.show_all()
```

Running from the command line (python myprogram.py) , my program runs normally on both Windows and Ubuntu. To formally state this as a question: how can I solve this problem and successfully create a functional "frozen" python executable?

Answer (score 0):

My best solution for this was to rewrite the program to use the qtwebkit library. Plays much nicer with py2exe.